# call to a method from external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have 2 javaScript files.
I tried call to a method from one file to the other file but I get an error that my method is didn't exists ("TypeError: Object # has no method 'getServer'").

There is the method from the first file:

```
function getServer(app, server)
{
  var socket = require("socket.io");
  app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    if(request.accepts("text/html"))
    {
      app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
      response.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    }
  });

  var io = socket.listen(server);
  io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
  ............................................
  ............................................
  });
```

there is the call to the method from the second file:

```
var msgServer = require('./firstFile.js');
msgServer.getServer(app, server);
```

In the first file I connect to server and listen on port.
I want to sent this server to the secont file.
I need the server and app in the second file to use the socket.io.

thanks for reply (:

Comment: Does the first file enclose getServer inside another variable and/or function or is it in the global namespace?

Comment: are you setting `module.exports.getServer = getServer` or creating a new object for `module.exports` that contains `getServer`

Comment: It is in the global namespace.

Comment: I didn't use the module.exports at all

Comment: Add: `module.exports.getServer = getServer;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `exports` var:

```
exports.getServer = function(app, server)
{
  var socket = require("socket.io");
  app.get("/", function(request, response) {
  ............................................
  ............................................
  });
```

It allows you to set this function avalaible for every file.

ANother way to do this:

```
module.exports = {
   getServer: funnction(app, server){...}
 }
```

Comment: See: [Modules: The module object](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_object) for more information.

Comment: Also, I would almost always recommed the `module.exports` syntax. Simple `exports` is just an reference (alias), can get overwritten by accident and lead to unclear situations and problems. It's in the best practices, I think.